# Is there a way to make angle lines and border lines of `polygon()` of different linewidth?

Tags: r, graphics

It seems that, in `polygon()`, `lwd` will change the linewidth of both borders and the angle lines. Is there a way to control them separately without calling `polygon()` twice?

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:

```
polygon(
    ## repeat x and y coordinates = two conformal polygons
    rep(c(0,1,.5,0),2),
    rep(c(0,0,1,0),2),
    angle = 45, density = 10,
    ## vector of line widths, one per polygon
    lwd = c(5,1)
)
```